# Is it possible to override static method in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Hello imagine that we have following class

```
Manager{
   public static void doSth(){
      // some logic
   };
}
```

How to override that method in kotlin?

I've tired to use

```
fun Manager.doSth(){}
```

but Its applied to instance not a static type.

Purpose of doing that is to avoid using PowerMockito

Comment: What you call "override" would actually mean "replace", i.e., monkey-patch the original declaring class. You can't override non-virtual methods.

Comment: Polymorphism and the static keyword are conflicting concepts. What you are suggesting is not possible because it does not make sense. I suggest you read up on [what static really means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Comment: @Marko Topolnik the correct term is "shadowing"

Comment: @Pawel Shadowing is much lighter-weight, it just affects the resolution of unqualified names. This is not what OP is after.

Comment: I didn't know monkey-patch before, but I will read about it.
Don't understand why sb downvoted it? Does this question break stackoverflow rules? If not, why you did it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik does "monkey-patch" is the only solution for that?
Do you know if PowerMockito use it to replace static methods?

Comment: I can only suppose what it does: jack into the class loading mechanism and replace the bytecode of a static method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short Answer**

No

**"Short" Explanation**

You can only override virtual methods and also you can shadow/replace static methods in Java, but you can't shadow a "static" method in Kotlin as the static method will not be available using the child class qualifier already. And even when using extension methods, you simply can't do it for either static or non-static as **the member function will always win**(see the example below). What you can do is to subclass the parent and add a new companion object that has a method with the same name as the parent and call the parent method from inside.

**Full Explanation**

- Static methods can't be overridden. It's called shadowing as you hide
  a method with another one.
- There are no static methods in Kotlin, so what you can do is using the
  `companion object` which behaves similarly and you can access the method
  of the companion object as if it were a java static method using only
  the class name as a qualifier but you can't access the methods of
  companion object of a parent class from its child like Java.
- You can't shadow a static method in Kotlin as the static method will not be available using the child class qualifier already, but you can write another companion object and add a method with the same name and call the
  parent method from there as the method from parent can't be accessed
  with the child class name qualifier.
- You can't make an extension method that shadows a companion object
  method or even overrides a member method. If a class has a member
  function and an extension function is defined which has the same
  receiver type, the same name and is applicable to given arguments,
  the member always wins.
- [Companion object extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions): You can write an extension method to
  the companion object, but if a member of that companion object has
  the same signature the member will always win.

### Example

```
open class A {
    fun foo() {
        println("A.foo()")
    }
    companion object {
        fun bar() {
            println("A.Companion.bar()")
        }
    }
}

class B: A()

fun A.foo() {
   println("A.foo() extension")
}

fun A.Companion.bar() {
    println("A.Companion.bar() extension")
}

fun A.Companion.baz() {
    println("A.Companion.baz() extension")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    A().foo() // prints A.foo()
    A.bar() // prints A.Companion.bar()
    A.baz() // prints A.Companion.baz() extension
    B.bar() // COMPILE ERROR
}
```

Comment: I cannot not override static method in anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that the static method from the parent can't be accessed from the child's qualifier so it can't be shadowed.

Using extensions, you simply can't do it for either static or non-static as the member function will always win. 

What you can do is to subclass the parent and add a new companion object that has a method with the same name as the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in Kotlin. The problem is that there is no `static` keyword in Kotlin. There is a similar concept (`companion object`) but the problem is that your original Java class doesn't have one.

`static` methods don't support inheritance either so you can't help this on the Java side.

If you want to declare extension methods which are "static" (eg: put them on a `companion object`) you can do this:

```
class Manager {

    companion object
}

fun Manager.Companion.doSth() = println("sth")
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Manager.doSth()
```

**Note that** you can only augment *Kotlin* classes this way which **have** a `companion object`.