# Not able to extend Adapter from a custom ResyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, abstract-class

I'm trying to implement an empty state recycler view based on this [post](https://alexzh.com/2017/02/05/how-to-setemptyview-to-recyclerview/). I have migrated the solution to Kotlin, but the problem is I'm not able to extend **CustomRecyclerView.Adapter** (Adapter is an abstract class defined in RecyclerView) from the newly defined custom recycler view in Kotlin. And I have observed the same **CustomRecyclerView.Adapter** can be extended in Java.

### Custome RecyclerView implementation

```
open class CustomRecyclerView: RecyclerView {


private var emptyStateView : View? = null

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context , attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context,attrs)
constructor(context: Context , attrs: AttributeSet, defstyle: Int) : super(context,attrs,defstyle)


var observer: AdapterDataObserver = object : AdapterDataObserver() {

    override fun onChanged() {
        super.onChanged()
        initEmptyView()
    }

    override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
        initEmptyView()
    }

    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
        initEmptyView()
    }
}

private fun initEmptyView() {
    emptyStateView?.let {
        it.visibility = if (adapter == null || adapter!!.itemCount == 0) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        this@CustomRecyclerView.visibility = if (adapter == null || adapter!!.itemCount == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
}

override fun setAdapter(adapter: Adapter<*>?) {
    val oldAdapter = getAdapter()
    super.setAdapter(adapter)
    oldAdapter?.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(observer)
    adapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer)
}

/**
 * @param emptyView is the view which is going to display when the recycler view is empty
 * **/
fun setEmptyView(emptyView: View) {
    this.emptyStateView = emptyView
    initEmptyView()
}}
```

Adding images for the extension implementation in java and kotin

[image: Kotlin]
[image: java]

Comment: what is your problem exactly? In Kotlin you would extend the Adapter the same way you do it in Java: `class YourAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>()`. The tutorial you linked does exactly that. Are you getting any  IDE errors?

Comment: I'm getting the error: Unresolved reference Adapter

Comment: what you are probably doing is `class YourAdapter: YourCustomRecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>()`, what you *should* do instead is `class YourAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>()`. Because `Adapter` is part of the `RecyclerView` itself and not its subclasses, see RV source code line 6700: `public abstract static class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder> `

Comment: Thanks, @Droidman, that does make sense. Let me try with normal RecyclerView.Adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarise the comments: inherit from `RecyclerView.Adapter`, see below

```
YourAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>()
```

And just a hint, here's the Kotlin way to extend a class with multiple constructors:

```
class CustomRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

For more info, check [@JvmOverloads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/index.html)

Comment: adding more insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266313/is-it-possible-to-override-static-method-in-kotlin?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It should be RecyclerView.Adapter.. and set adapter to customRecyclerView.